# Can I give an enum an attribute in VB.NET (like I can do in Java)?

Tags: java, vb.net, enums

In Java I can do something like this:

```
enum Country {
    IRELAND("Europe"),
    FRANCE("Europe"),
    NIGERIA("Africa"),
    THAILAND("Asia");

    private String continent;

    Country(String continent) {
        this.continent = continent;
    }

    public String getContinent() {
        return continent;
    }
}
```

which allows me to do something like:

```
Country country1 = getCountryFromSomewhere();
Country country2 = Country.FRANCE;
System.out.print("country1 is in " + country1.getContinent());
System.out.print("country2 is in " + country2.getContinent());
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in VB.NET i.e. add the continent attribute to the country enum?

Comment: `THAILAND("Singapore")`... As a Singaporean, I can vouch completely that Singapore is not a continent and Thailand is a totally different place.

Comment: Corrected! My deepest apologies to the good people of Singapore (and Thailand)...

Comment: It's alright, I actually thought it was funny :)

Comment: @BoltClock: I wondered about that while writing my answer... but figured posting the answer would be more important than correcting it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this solution instead:

Declare enum:

```
Private Enum Country
    IRELAND
    FRANCE
    THAILAND
End Enum
```

Declare and initialise Dictionary (aka a map):

```
Dim countryContinentMap As IDictionary(Of Country, String) = New Dictionary(Of Country, String)
countryContinentMap.add(Country.IRELAND, "Europe")
countryContinentMap.add(Country.FRANCE, "Europe")
countryContinentMap.add(Country.THAILAND, "Asia")
```

which allows me to get the continent like this:

```
Dim franceContinent As String = countryContinentMap(Country.FRANCE)
```

Comment: The advantage of the enum is that you have your stuff at 1 place and don't need to change at many positions. Seems like VB.NET doesn't provide that like C# does. I would love to have a description for my Enums to simply iterate through them for example.

Answer (score 8):

(Apologies for using C# throughout - I believe the concepts are more about .NET than the language you happen to use; hopefully you're better at reading C# than I am at writing VB.)

Not directly - enums in .NET are just integer types with names for some of the values.

The closest you can come in .NET is to create a type with a fixed set of values. For example, in your case:

```
public sealed class Country
{
    public static readonly Country Ireland = new Country("Europe");
    public static readonly Country France = new Country("Europe");
    public static readonly Country Nigeria = new Country("Africa");
    public static readonly Country Thailand = new Country("Asia");

    private readonly string continent;

    public string Continent { get { return continent; } }

    private Country(string continent)
    {
        this.continent = continent;
    }
}
```

(I assume the VB.NET would be very similar.)

Note that this *doesn't* let you switch on the enum values.

If you want polymorphism, you can create nested subclasses which can still call the *private* constructor, which prevents any other subclasses being created.

One alternative to this is to use *attributes* on normal enums:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class ContinentAttribute : Attribute
{
    // etc
}

public enum Country
{
    [Continent("Europe")] Ireland = 1,
    [Continent("Europe")] France = 2,
    ...
}
```

You'd then need to use reflection to get at the `ContinentAttribute` and retrieve the string.

Note that here there isn't *really* a fixed set of values - you could write:

```
Country country = (Country) 15;
```

At that point you can't get the continent for it, and if you pass it to any methods which expect it to be a *real* country, you've got problems. That isn't the case with the earlier solution, where you really are restricted to those few values (and null).

Comment: How can someone write so much(worth reading) in so less time?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: He's not just someone.

Comment: Maybe something analogous to a preinitialized EnumMap?

Comment: Hi Jon, I've upvoted your answer as I appreciate the time you took to write it out and you did answer my question (no, it's not possible). I'm not going to mark it as the accepted answer though as I probably won't use either solution (and I did specify I was using VB.NET).

Comment: @CodeClimber: That's fair enough. (You really don't want me writing VB though. It would probably be horrible code :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code:

Imports System.ComponentModel

Imports System.Reflection

```
Public Enum enumOrderStatus
    <Description("None")>
    None
    <Description("Sent")>
    Sent
    <Description("Accepted")>
    Accepted
    <Description("Cancelled")>
    Cancelled
    <Description("Declined")>
    Declined
End Enum


Public Function GetEnumDescription(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
    Dim fi As FieldInfo = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString())
    Dim aattr() As DescriptionAttribute = DirectCast(fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())
    If aattr.Length > 0 Then
        Return aattr(0).Description
    Else
        Return EnumConstant.ToString()
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this in my application. Still looking for something even easier.

What do you think about it?

```
Public Sub Init()
    Dim values() As Integer = CType([Enum].GetValues(GetType(MyEnum)), Integer())
    For i As Integer = 0 To values.Count - 1
        Me.contextMenuInGUI.Items.Add(Me.GetEnumDescription(i))
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetEnumDescription(ByVal i As Integer) As String
    Select Case i
        Case MyEnum.Comment
            Return "Description for Comment"

        Case MyEnum.SomeEnumValueInCamelCase
            Return "Value without camel case (€)(%)(@)"
    End Select
    Return "Add a case in Class:GetEnumDescription"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension method for your Enum

Usage example:

```
dim description = TableTag.Important.GetDescription()
```

Definition example:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace Foo

  Public Enum TableTag

    <Description("Identifies tables that should be availible for writing as table or view to the model database")>
    Important

    <Description("Example for a table group that helps to select disctinct tables")>
    CustomGroup

  End Enum

  Public Module TableTagExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function GetDescription(enumValue As TableTag) As String

      Dim fieldInfo As FieldInfo = enumValue.GetType().GetField(enumValue.ToString())
      Dim attributes = DirectCast(fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())

      If attributes.Length > 0 Then
        Return attributes(0).Description
      Else
        Return enumValue.ToString()
      End If

    End Function

  End Module

End Namespace
```