# Const Vs. Enum for Method Parameter

Tags: c#, vb.net, enums, constants

I have a seemingly very basic question. I'm trying to decide whether or not constants strings would really be better than enums with MyEnum.ToString() called for a high performance application.

I have a class, enum, method like this...

```
    Public Enum MyEnum
        MyValue1
        MyValue2
    End Enum

    Public Class MyImportantClass

            Public Sub Foo(ByVal enumerationValue As MyEnum)

            ' Some code in here that needs to do this at some point
            Dim str As String = enumerationValue.ToString()

    End Sub

    End Class
```

I understand enumerationValue.ToString() has some performance issues. However, another developer suggested instead of using Enums, use Constant Strings. My problem is that the method parameter is then a string, and the caller can then pass whatever he wants. Not just any string will work, obviously, so this is a run-time bug.

```
Public Sub Foo(ByVal enumerationValue As String)

    ' Some code in here that needs to do this at some point
    '   Dim str As String = enumerationValue

End Sub
```

I want the safety of the enum, but the performance of a constant. As I said, I'm looking for a way to have my cake and eat it too.

Comment: Stick with the enum - it's safer and I see no great performance advantage at all with the string constant.

Comment: enumerationValue.ToString() has some performance issues? I think whatever performance you are worried about is negligible.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the `.ToString` ends up being a performance bottleneck for you.  Why not try it that way and profile it?

Comment: You should always profile your performance issues, when aiming for efficiency -- especially in a language that operates at a higher level of abstraction.  The issue with performance without profiling is that the compiler is going to optimize your code in somewhat unpredictable ways.  Some "optimizations" can actually make code slower.  Always check.

Comment: While I agree that I would use enum unless it really is necessary, based on testing, to use strings, I do need to correct something.  You mentioned that one downfall of strings is that an invalid value can be passed in.  However, enums have the same problem.  Though certainly less likely, you could still pass an invalid value such as `Foo(CType(-54321, MyEnum))`.

Comment: If performance is a concern, and you are not exposing this function in a public API (i.e. the sole user of this function is you), with perfect documentation, you can take the path of const. I suggest this because consts are fully evaluated at compile time and performs better than those that get evaluated at runtime.

Comment: If you do use constants, I would put them in their own class so that you can still use the same enum-like syntax of `MyConstants.MyValue1`.

Comment: @Steven Doggart - wicked idea, but even this doesn't guarantee type safety; the next guy can subclass `MyConstants`. I don't think anything short of `Enum` is going to prevent bad values from leaking into the OP's Sub.

Comment: @MarkFisher I never said that putting them in a class in any way stops invalid values from being passed.  I completely agree that it does not.  I was just saying it makes the code slightly more self-documenting that way.  However, as I said in my first comment, it is incorrect to say that making it an enum prevents invalid values from being passed.  Even if you use an enum, you still have to handle the fact that an invalid integer could be passed in.

Comment: @Steven Doggart - You're right, of course, even `Enum` doesn't protect you, and I don't think it's that unlikely. I can see an unobservant programmer writing exactly the code you provided as an example to 'fix' the OP's method so it will accept integers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick with enum, it's a lot more user frendly with passing as a parameter to a function. The IDE can pop-up the list of available items.

To convert your enum to string, you could have a dictionnary of (Enum, String)

or

There's some nice articles on how to put attributes on your enum, this way you can convert it to a string.

[Can I give an enum an attribute in VB.NET (like I can do in Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915349/can-i-give-an-enum-an-attribute-in-vb-net-like-i-can-do-in-java)

http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/03/12/enum-with-string-values-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Enum is by far the way to go. Somewhat self-documenting and definately falling into the 'pit of success' becuase you'll never get bogus data.

I don't know for sure but I would suspect .ToString() does nice stuff - don't worry about it. It gets called a lot!

Comment: I was told that enum .ToString() uses reflection to get the name of the enum value and that would be a performance problem. This is an operation that could be called a 100 times per second. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this may not be what you want, but it provides for type safety and prevents you from having to do a `ToString` later. First set up a class w/ one property that doesn't have a setter, and a New method that does the setting:

```
Public Class MyEnumObj
    Private _Value As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Value As String
        Get
            Return _Value
        End Get
    End Property
    Private Sub New()
        ' Hide the default constructor '
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(inValue As String)
        _Value = inValue
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then declare your "constants":

```
Public MyValue1 As New MyEnumObj("MyValue1")
Public MyValue2 As New MyEnumObj("MyValue2")
```

They're not constant but can't be modified, and I think by proper use of `Friend` you can arrange it so nobody else can create the objects, either. Now you can say:

```
Public Sub Foo(Optional ByVal enumerationValue As MyEnumObj = Nothing)

        ' Some code in here that needs to do this at some point '
        Dim str As String = If(enumerationValue IsNot Nothing, enumerationValue.Value, String.Empty)

End Sub
```

This may be overkill, but objects do tend to lend themselves to type safety.

Comment: I was working on something very similar to this. My only snag was that the enum in question is being passed as an optional parameter, which has to be some kind of constant like an empty string or an enum.

Comment: @Danny Ellis Jr. - I've updated my implementation of `Foo` to use `Optional`. Does that work for you?